# Can you get multiple Energy Resistance enchantments on your armor?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, armor

When I was looking at the [Energy Resistance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/energy-resistance/) magic armor and shield special ability, I noticed that it didn't say whether or not one could get the enchantment for multiple different kinds of energy. For instance, could one get Energy Resistance Cold and Energy Resistance Sonic both enchanted on their armor for 36,000g?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say so.  In fact, there's at least one [specific suit of armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/invincible-armor/) that grants resistance to multiple kinds of energy already.

Comment: Not directly answering the question, but something to bear in mind- _energy resistance_, though it has a flat price, is considered equivalent to a +4 bonus.  Without some special dispensation, as with the armor previously presented, you won't fit more than two.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe that is the case. While energy resistance is on the random table for a +4 ability, it has a fixed price, not a bonus. So, in theory, if you had enough money, you could add as many as you wanted. I would also disagree that the Invincible armour is comparable at all.

Comment: The spells and feats necessary to craft _armor of energy resistance_ and _Invincible armor_ coincide, implying they get their resistance the same way.  As to the bonus, that's a bit more iffy, I'll agree.  While listed in the +4 abilities, it doesn't flat out say to treat it as a +4 bonus, just to add 18,000 gp to the enhancement bonus to determine price.  I'd argue that the intent is to pay a fixed price for that particular +4 bonus, rather than pay a similar amount for a free special ability- especially since there isn't a section for "no effective bonus" abilities.